# Next.js 13.4 and NextAuth Type Error: 'AuthOptions' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, next-auth

I'm currently working on a Next.js 13.4 project and trying to set up NextAuth using the app/ router. However, I'm encountering a type error that I can't seem to resolve.

Here's my route.ts file:

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

And here's the error message when running 'npm run build':

```
- info Linting and checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/Users/Luk/Documents/Workspace/zerotwo-dash/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"), "GET" | "POST" | "HEAD" | "OPTIONS" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | "PATCH" | "config" | ... 6 more ... | "runtime", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'authOptions' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'AuthOptions' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   GET?: Function
  10 |   HEAD?: Function
  11 |   OPTIONS?: Function
```

I really have no idea whats happening here... when looking up the 'AuthOptions' on t he github page from nextauth i see nothing wrong with my code..

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the issue is with exporting the authOptions with handlers in the route.ts file for nextJs 13.4+, just by **removing the export from the authOptions** you will be good to go. That was the reason seperating the authOptions worked :).

route.ts  -->

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

// Here we removed the export
const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },`enter code here`
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

In case we want the authOptions somewhere else we can do that like --->

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

// Here we removed the export
const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },`enter code here`
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST, authOptions }
```

Comment: In case we want the authOptions somewhere else we can do that like --->
```ts
export { handler as GET, handler as POST, authOptions }
```
This doesn't work in my side.

Comment: @jack What is the code you have can you share please to assist with possible issues?

Comment: This is not the right answer, nextjs has a signature check for the exported object which doesn't include authOptions. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50870#issuecomment-1598655396

Answer (score 33):

Okay i solved it myself. For anyone having the same issue, i created a new file @/utils/authOptions.ts:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}
```

and used it in @/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:

```
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/authOptions";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I changed the imports a little (import NextAuth from "next-auth/next")
I dont know why this works tbh, but it does... even changing the imports around in my route.ts as it was before wont fix it. Only if its seperated like that...

Comment: Moving the authOptions to another file worked for me

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the problem?

Comment: I hate that this fixed my problem too and yet I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution with didn't actually work for me on Next.js 14.0.4 and Next-Auth 5.0.0-beta.5, so I came up with another one.

That is, just `export` the two handlers. No need to move the authOptions elsewhere.

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  /* ... your config ... */
});

export const GET = handler.handlers.GET;
export const POST = handler.handlers.POST;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was using "as never" like this --->

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '@/app/lib/authOptions';

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions) as never;

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

---

```
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: 'Email Address',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Email address...'
                },
                password: {
                    label: 'Password',
                    type: 'password',
                    placeholder: 'Password...'
                },

            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                // your authorization logic here
                
                // return {
                //     name: ...
                //     email: ...
                //    id: ...
                // };
            }
        })
    ]
};
```