# Receiving Login Page on Every Refresh with Next.js 13 and NextAuth

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

Question:
I've recently started using Next.js 13 and NextAuth for authentication in my application. However, I'm encountering a puzzling issue where the login page appears on every page refresh. I've followed the documentation closely and reviewed my code, but I can't seem to pinpoint the cause of the problem. My suspections are on how I have wrapped my session provider or my layout component.

Issue:
Upon refreshing any page, the application redirects to the login page even though the user was previously authenticated. This behavior is unexpected and doesn't align with the desired user experience.

I have this components/Layout.js

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

import Nav from "./Nav";
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <div className={"bg-blue-900 w-screen h-screen flex items-center"}>
        <div className="text-center w-full">
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              signIn("google");
            }}
            className="bg-white p-2 px-4 rounded-lg"
          >
            Login With
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className={"bg-blue-900 min-h-screen flex"}>
      <Nav />
      <div className="bg-white flex-grow mt-2 mr-2 rounded-lg p-4">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I have this root layout.js file

```
import { NextAuthProvider } from "./NextAuthProvider";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import "./globals.css";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          <Layout>{children}</Layout>
        </NextAuthProvider>
        ;
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I solved it before by using getServerSession but now it stopped working and gave me a jwt session error so I removed my workaround.

Edit:
This my pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js file:

```
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

// For more information on each option (and a full list of options) go to
// https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
export const authOptions = {
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This is my project structure:
[image: Following the docs and the example]

Answer (score 0):

One way you could probably solve this problem is to move away from using `layout.js` and use `_app.tsx`. This method will wrap your entire application with next-auth.

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import Script from "next/script";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

This implementation is a lot simpler to use. It's also how they suggest in  the documentation. The issue could also lie in you `[...nextauth].js` file setup. So if you can post that I can help rework some of the code.

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

If you follow the above implementation you can use `getServerSideProps` to redirect users if they are authenticated or unauthenticated or use middleware.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

Comment: I can not use _app.jsx and remove the layout.js file because it will complain on missing root layout

Comment: @JOHn can you post your directory structure?

Comment: I have attached an Image now

Comment: I also tried following his example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388994/next-js-13-4-and-nextauth-type-error-authoptions-is-not-assignable-to-type-n . But no change at all still the same problem