# Next.js can’t build

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am working on a Next.js project using *NextAuth.js*. When defining my `authOptions`, I get a TypeScript error saying that my `authOptions` object is not compatible with the expected type for `AuthOptions`. Here is my code:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials 1");
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        const isCorrectPassword = user
          ? await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.hashedPassword || ""
            )
          : false;

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials 2");
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The exact error is:

> "Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("D:/Projects/NextJs/Adminpanel/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"), "config" | "generateStaticParams" | ...>' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'. Property 'authOptions' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'AuthOptions' is not assignable to type 'never'."

How can I fix this problem and make sure that my `authOptions` object has the correct type for `AuthOptions`?

Comment: Use a separate file for your authOptions.  See [here per the maintainer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50870) and [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76389403/3577849).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need authOptions anywhere else, just get rid of `export` in this part:

```
export const authOptions
```

If you do need authOptions, create a separate file for them and then import in here:

```
  import {authOptions} from "..."

    const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
    export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: Could you show it to me on my code?

Comment: @Jonaskop44 just delete `export` from this part: **export** const authOptions: AuthOptions = { adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma), ....}, it should be: `const authOptions: AuthOptions = { adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma), ....},`

Comment: Thank you. The error is gone now but now I have an error with my middleware: ƒ Middleware 213 kB

`
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/"
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*"],
};
`

Comment: @Jonaskop44 it could be a similar error which is connected to `export`, but in this case I don't know for sure